# What is the proper way to refer to ES.next static class properties?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-next, es6-class

I have the following code, which works as expected, but I'm not convinced it's the right way:

```
'use strict';

class Upload {
  static uploadCount = 20;

  constructor(props) {
    Upload.uploadCount++;
  }

  static get count() {
    return this.uploadCount;
  }
}

const up1 = new Upload({
  name: 'Wow.pdf',
  size: 123123,
});

const up2 = new Upload({
  name: 'doit.pdf',
  size: 9999999,
});

console.log(Upload.count);
```

Why can't `constructor` refer to the static var via `this.uploadCount` like the static getter can? Is there a better/correct way to track the amount of instantiated `Upload` objects?

Comment: fwiw, at chromium 52 logs `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`, which appears to point to `static uploadCount = 20;`?. See [Static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods)

Comment: That's ok, I'm using babel rather than relying on the browser to support the ES6 proposals.

Comment: Nit: Not an "ES6 proposal", just a syntax proposal for ECMAScript.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in the constructor refers to the object instance that was just created.  static properties are properties on the constructor itself, not the instance.  So, if you want to refer to them from an instance method, you have to use the constructor name as in `Upload.uploadCount`.

---

FYI, the syntax you are using:

```
static uploadCount = 20;
```

is not a standard part of ES2015 and the only place I know of for sure that it works is with Babel.  If you want portable code and aren't using Babel, you should not be using that syntax.  You can change to the old-fashioned:

```
Upload.uploadCount = 20;
```

And put that after the class definition and have portability.

---

FYI, the syntax you are using for static properties is proposed for a future JS revision, but last I checked it had not been decided upon yet.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So is `Upload.uploadCount` the correct way to reference the static property from within `constructor`?

Comment: @ffxsam - Yes that would be how to do it from anywhere that isn't a static method.  Since static methods are referenced via the class name, the `this` value in a static method happens to be set to the class name.

Comment: You edited your post just as I commented :) Ok sounds good, just wanted to make sure I was doing this the right way. Thanks!

Comment: Throws error at chromium 52 `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`?

Comment: @guest271314 - Huhhh?  What are you talking about?  What code related to this question creates that error?  My recommendation is to refer to statics as `Upload.uploadCnt`.

Comment: `static uploadCount = 20` "The static keyword defines a static method for a class." [Static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods)

Comment: @guest271314 - If you want to discuss another error in the OP's code, then either make your own answer or comment to the OP, not to me.  I was answering the specific question asked which was how to refer to static properties.

Comment: Well, OP is asking _you_ a Question. You are the most learned in this topic. The documentation refers to `static` as a _method_. If OP wants their code to run on all platforms, they would probably want to be aware of the result at different browsers. Will comment to OP the same.

Comment: @guest271314 - FYI, some implementations support the static property syntax the OP is using.  For example, Babel supports it.  Apparently, since the OP didn't seem to have an error there, their implementation must be supporting it.  I agree, it's not a portable syntax.

Comment: @jfriend00 _"I agree, it's not a portable syntax."_ That is the only thing was attempting to convey.

Comment: @guest271314 - Well, it took awhile for me to understand that's what you were saying.  I will add that to my answer.